# In Java 8, how can i filter a list of objects by grouping and summing?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Let's say i have a list of objects :

```
objList
Integer id Double price String userCode
         1         10.5             AAA
         2         9.5              AAA
         3         10.0             AAA
         4         10.0             BBB
         5         10.0             BBB
```

and i want to modify the list so i can group by userCode and sum the prices, like this:

```
 objList
    Integer id Double price String userCode
             1         30.0             AAA
             4         20.0             BBB
```

How can i achieve this in Java 8 with lambda? If possible, i would want to achieve this without creating a new list and without losing the other object fields(like in this case, the id). I've already seen other answers for this, but every other answer needs for the creation of a new list or collection.

I've already tried this :

```
Collection<Obj1> objListSorted = objList.stream().collect(
                    toMap(
                            f -> f.getId(),
                            Function.identity(),
                            (s, a) -> new Obj1(
                                        (int) s.getId(), 
                                        s.getPrice() + a.getPrice(),
                                        s.getUserCode()
                                        ))
                          )
                    .values();
```

But in actuality i'm working with a model class that has 80+ fields, so i would like to achieve this by not creating a new instance of Obj1. I do want to retain the first ID in the group, as well as retaining all the other fields of the object as they are. Also, if possible, i would like to have the final output as a List instead of a Collection.

Comment: What have you try?

Comment: "*How can i achieve this in Java 8 with lambda?*" - by using Java 8 Streams with `Collectors.toMap()`.

Comment: Apart from not showing what you tried, you also fail to mention why you would want to retain the ids 1 and 4 in your expected result.

Comment: @daniu I'm *guessing* that OP is grouping by `userCode` and retaining the first occurrence of `id` for each group. But that's a *guess* and I do agree that it should've been clarified.

Comment: @Fureeish Yes, one can also assume that he wants to use the lowest id in the group though.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify what i've tried and what i want to achieve.

Comment: *"achieve this by not creating a new instance of Obj1"* That is impossible considering you want `price` to have a value that doesn't exist in the original collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

### SOLUTION 1

One way of doing this is

```
List<Pricing> allPricings = getAllPricings();

List<Pricing> result = allPricings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pricing::getUserCode))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .reduce((f1,f2) -> new Pricing(f1.getId(),f1.getPrice() + f2.getPrice(),f1.getUserCode())))
        .map(f -> f.get())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### SOLUTION 2

This is a more compact way

```
Collection<Pricing> result2 = 
        allPricings.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Pricing::getUserCode, 
                        collectingAndThen(
                                reducing((p1, p2)-> new Pricing(p1.getId(),p1.getPrice() + p2.getPrice(),p2.getUserCode())), Optional::get)))
                .values();
```

### SOLUTION 3

If you don't want to create the object try the below one. But one side effect with this implementation is that it alters the original list content, so better don't use the original list, instead use a cloned one.

```
Collection<Pricing> result3 =
        allPricings.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Pricing::getUserCode,
                        collectingAndThen(
                                reducing((p1, p2)-> {
                                    p1.setPrice(p1.getPrice() + p2.getPrice());
                                    return p1;
                                }), Optional::get)))
                .values();
```

**Sample function for getAllPricings**

```
private static List<Pricing> getAllPricings() {
    List<Pricing> pricings = new ArrayList<>();
    pricings.add(new Pricing(1, 10.5, "AAA"));
    pricings.add(new Pricing(2, 9.5, "AAA"));
    pricings.add(new Pricing(3, 10.0, "AAA"));
    pricings.add(new Pricing(4, 10.0, "BBB"));
    pricings.add(new Pricing(5, 10.0, "BBB"));
    return pricings;
}
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 30,
    "userCode": "AAA"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "price": 20,
    "userCode": "BBB"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupingBy` with a downstream `Collector`. You can use `reducing` for adding the prices, however that returns an `Optional` which you don't want, but it's guaranteed to be present so you can just `get()` its result.

```
Collection<Obj1> added = objList.stream()
       .collect(groupingBy(Obj1::getUserCode),
                collectingAndThen(
                    reducing((o1, o2) -> { 
                        // not creating another instance, but: side effect!
                        o1.setPrice(o1.getPrice()+o2.getPrice()); 
                        return o1; 
                    }),
                    opt -> opt.get()
                ))
       .values();
```

It makes little sense to require this to become a `List` since there is no ordering in the created values, so any you add would be arbitrary. You can of course do

```
List<Obj1> asList = new ArrayList<>(added);
```

and have your `List`. If you wanted to have the result ordered, you can do the `groupingBy` using a `TreeMap` and an applicable `Comparator`, this guarantees the result of `values()` to also be sorted by that (you'll still need to make it a `List` though).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question :
which form of groupingBy() should i import in this particular example?

Comment: @LordGriffith You don't import a certain "form", `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy` will do.

Comment: i have a problem with this line : .collect(groupingBy(Obj1::getUserCode),  if i try to add my own object :          .collect(groupingBy(pricesDTO::getUserDefExtCode) it gives me a compile error, "no suitable method found".